# Having an ambiguity issue in C#

Tags: c#

I have the follow program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CaptureFunction(MyFunction); // This line gets an error: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: CaptureFunction(System.Func<object,object>) and CaptureFunction(System.Func<int,int>)"
        CaptureFunction(MyFunction2);
    }

    static void CaptureFunction(Func<object,object> myFunction)
    {
        myFunction.DynamicInvoke(3);
    }

    static void CaptureFunction(Func<int, int> myFunction)
    {
        myFunction.DynamicInvoke(3);
    }

    static object MyFunction(object a)
    {
        if (a is int)
            return ((int) a)*3;
        return 0;
    }

    static int MyFunction2(int a)
    {
        return a * 3;
    }
```

I am trying to figure out why I am getting an ambiguity error at that line. They clearly have two different parameter signatures. I understand that an `int` can also be boxed into an `object`, however, I would except C# to call the `CaptureFunction(Func<int, int>)` method if I pass actual `int` values, otherwise it should call the other `CaptureFunction()` method. Can someone please explain this and please offer a possible work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>This is due to covariance/contavariance introduced in .Net 4. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) for info. Because `int` is castable to `object` the compiler can't decide which function you are pointing to (as Func is castable to Func)</strike> Sorry, not .Net 4

The following compiles:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CaptureFunction((Func<object,object>)MyFunction); // This line gets an error: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: CaptureFunction(System.Func<object,object>) and CaptureFunction(System.Func<int,int>)"
    CaptureFunction(MyFunction2);
}

static void CaptureFunction(Func<object,object> myFunction)
{
    myFunction.DynamicInvoke(3);
}

static void CaptureFunction(Func<int,int> myFunction)
{
    myFunction.DynamicInvoke(3);
}

static object MyFunction(object a)
{
    if(a is int)
        return ((int)a)*3;
    return 0;
}

static int MyFunction2(int a)
{
    return a * 3;
}
```

Note the casting to `Func<object,object>`

Comment: See I get that. But can't the compiler figure it out when I pass the actual values? Like if I pass pure `int` values, it should call the `int` method...and if I pass anything else other than pure `int` values, it should call the `object` method?

Comment: This is not correct; he's not using 4.0. It's because the delegate being passed is overloaded and either one could be valid... covariance/contravariance are not involved.

Comment: @AllanChua It's not correct, though. See above comment. (it's not 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dynamic if you are using C#.net 4.0

```
    static void CaptureFunction(Func<dynamic, dynamic> myFunction)
    {
        myFunction.DynamicInvoke(3);
    }
```

if you are not using 4.0 then just use object type.

```
    static void CaptureFunction(Func<object, object> myFunction)
    {
        myFunction.DynamicInvoke(3);
    }
```

remove the other overload of CaptureFunction which has a type of int.

Comment: LOL I am using the <object, object> signature. The compiler is giving me an error though when I use it. That is why I posted my question.

Comment: I mean remove the overload which has an int type. It would be solve then :) int is derived from object and that is the very reason why you're compiler is confused during compile time.

Comment: Oh I see. That would work, but then I would have to type check each parameter for figure it out if its double or int or long or whatever it is. The example I provided in my question is only a fragment

Comment: it would only take a few checks right? something like this if(a is int || a is long || a is double) then convert it to long, perform operation on it then return it to a type that you would desire

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a delegate for MyFunction... but which one? It could be either... either would work.

There are overloads of CaptureFunction that will accept either MyFunction signature. So it has no way to know which one you mean.

Comment: Can't the compiler figure it out when I pass the actual values? Like if I pass pure int values, it should call the int method...and if I pass anything else other than pure int values, it should call the object method?

Comment: You aren't passing any parameters right then; you are talking about a later method call that's largely unrelated. No; the compiler can (and should) not make any assumptions based on that. Maybe you mean to use the object version passing ints.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the function given satisfies both delegate signatures. You can work around this by declaring the func explicitly:

```
Func<int, int> intFunc = MyFunction2;
Func<object, object> objFunc = MyFunction;
CaptureFunction(intFunc);
CaptureFunction(objFunc);
```